# Switching user per role

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am writing an `Ansible` playbook.

It has a series of commands that run as root, followed by a series of commands that run as another user (call it `user1`).

I know I can switch to `user1` by attaching

```
become: yes
become_user: user1
```

at the end of every command that runs as `user1`, but this will make the playbook unnecessarily lengthy and ugly.

Can I switch to `user1` and run all tasks as `user1` afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `block` in 2.x to run multiple tasks as a particular user:

```
- block:
    - task1
    - task2
    - task3
  become: yes
  become_user: user1

- task4
```

You can also set `become_user` for a role's tasks:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  roles:
    - role: some-role
      become: true
      become_user: user1
```